# Rails 3: Unknown validator: 'PresenceValidator' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Rails 3.2.19, Ruby 1.9.3p547.

After adding a few gems to development (`pry` and its various dependencies), any validation in the form `validates :some_field, some_default_rails_validator: true` fails. Prior to bundling, all of these validations worked perfectly. Rolling back the Gemfile and re-bundling has no effect.

Other folks seem to have had issues with custom (or misspelled) validators, but the failures are all for Rails default validators. For example, running `rails c` gives me:

> `Users/MY_USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@MY_APP/gems/activemodel-3.2.19/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:96 in 'rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'PresenceValidator' (Argument Error)`

which traces down to

> `from /Users/MY_USER/MY_APP/app/models/document.rb:4 in '<class:SomeModel>'`

In the model file, I have:

```
validates :title, presence: true
```

`PresenceValidator` is a default Rails validator, and somehow a gem seems to have borked that. I'm not really sure what to do (besides nuking the app from space and reinitializing my development environment).

Comment: Try opening console and type: `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator`

Comment: I would, but I can't open the rails console since `eager_load`ing models is what causes this issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which `pry` version do you have?  `bundle show pry`.  I was able to use such validation with `pry-0.10.1` installed in the same rails and ruby as yours.

Comment: `pry` was added in a branch. I went to master, which doesn't have those changes, and reinitialized my gemset, and the problem still occurs, so `pry` and the related gems would seem not to be the culprit.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Any resolution yet ?

Comment: As I recall (obviously a while ago by now), a system restart fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? It worked for me.

```
validates :title, :presence=>true
```

Comment: Changing the hash syntax won't make a difference. Either form is perfectly legal. If there was a syntax error, this might be relevant, but there was a validator error.

Comment: I was having this same issue and this worked!! Both should be valid statement, any idea why one would work and the other results in a validation error? @JoshuaGrossoReinstateCMs