# Can't eagerload classes | Rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Rails: 4.2.5**

I'm using **STI** and needed to get all Subclasses.

But as in dev environment, rails does Lazy Loading. So `Model.subclasses` and `Model.descendants` always return `[]`

Googling sent me to this **issue**: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3364

And the above issue suggested following solution to put as initializer:

```
ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
  Rails.application.eager_load!
end
```

And on that I'm getting following **exception**:

```
/Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:120:in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'PersenceValidator' (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:117:in `block in validates'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:113:in `each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:113:in `validates'
    from /Users/vmac1/rails_projects/survd/app/models/sub_service.rb:7:in `<class:SubService>'
    from /Users/vmac1/rails_projects/survd/app/models/sub_service.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/vmac1/rails_projects/survd/app/models/buffet_service.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
    from /Users/vmac1/rails_projects/survd/config/initializers/eagerload_subclasses.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `call'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/vmac1/rails_projects/survd/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.6.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/vmac1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you got a typo somewhere (persence vs presence) ?

Comment: No. The moment I remove the above initializer, exception goes way

Comment: The eager loading could (by definition) be causing s model that's not normally loaded, with a typo, to be loaded. Exception message is weird otherwise

Comment: Yes it is weird to me too. Same type of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516101/rails-3-unknown-validator-presencevalidator-argumenterror, but that doesn't help yet

Comment: Right you were. Caught the typo. Pardon for bothering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the actual error is a validation typo. But in regards to the original problem, Rails 4.2 eager-loads all classes in production [by default](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-5/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/production.rb.tt#L11), so you'd just have to change the `eager_load` and `cache_classes` setting in your other environments to get the same behavior. However, this will make development much more unpleasant since you'll have to restart the server every time you make a code change.

What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve by listing all subclasses? There might be another design that would avoid that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Typo of `persence` instead of `presence`